# Functions as template parameters issue

Tags: c++, templates

I have this problem bothering me. I have the FSM class which associate keys to callbacks

```
class FSM
{
public:

typedef bool (FSM::*InCallback_t)( int );
typedef std::map< std::string, InCallback_t > Table;

// Since I would like to allow the user to register both functors and class member    functions
template< typename Callback_t, bool (Callback_t::*CallbackFunct_t)(int) >
bool callback( int x )
{
    return (Callback_t().*CallbackFunct_t)( x );
}

void addCallback( const std::string& iKey, InCallback_t iCallback )
{
    _table.insert( std::make_pair( iKey, iCallback ) );
}

    [ ... ]

private:
    Table _table;
};
```

And some callbacks classes

```
class CallbackBase
{
public:

    bool operator()( int x ){ return doCall( x ); }

private:
    virtual bool doCall( int x ){ return true; }
};


class Callback: public CallbackBase
{
private:
    bool doCall( int x )
    {
        std::cout << "Callback\n";
        return true;
    }
};
```

Now if into the main I do:

```
FSM aFSM;
// OK
aFSM.addCallback( "one", &FSM::callback< CallbackBase, &CallbackBase::operator() > );  
// KO
aFSM.addCallback( "two", &FSM::callback< Callback, &Callback::operator() > );
```

The first call is fine, in the second one compiler complains:

```
Test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
Test.cpp:104:77: error: no matching function for call to ‘FSM::addCallback(const char [4], <unresolved overloaded function type>)’
Test.cpp:104:77: note: candidate is:
Test.cpp:24:7: note: void FSM::addCallback(const string&, FSM::InCallback_t)
Test.cpp:24:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘FSM::InCallback_t’
```

Also notice that the following is fine

```
typedef bool (Callback::*Function_t)( int );
Function_t aFunction = &Callback::operator();
(Callback().*aFunction)( 5 );
```

Any idea?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Simone

Comment: Seems like a compiler bug. :|

Comment: Yes I supposed it too. It is quite strange

Comment: I had some problems with that too, using base-class functions (or operators) with a memberfunction-pointer of the derived class. In MSVC atleast, it just doesn't work in templates.

Comment: If you think you have a compiler bug, post the exact compiler version!

Comment: @Ben Yes sorry. Here it is  gcc version 4.6.0 20110603 (Red Hat 4.6.0-10) (GCC)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't defined Callback::operator(). There is no secound function for Callback just the function from CallbackBase which takes a CallbackBase and a int as parameters! This is why the compiler moans about "unresolved overloaded function type".

The type of the inherited function is bool (CallbackBase::*operator())(int). This function can be automatically converted to a bool (Callback::*operator())(int) because you can always apply a Callback to a function that accepts only a CallbackBase. This is the reason why the following works - it's a automatic cast happening there.

```
typedef bool (Callback::*Function_t)( int );
Function_t aFunction = &Callback::operator();
```

The problem happens with the template type deduction:

```
template< typename Callback_t, bool (Callback_t::*CallbackFunct_t)(int) >
with: Callback_t = Callback, CallbackFunct_t = bool (CallbackBase::*CallbackFunct_t)(int)
```

This doesn't work since the types that given via Callback_t and the type required by the function pointer do not match when instanciating the callback function.
You can resolve the problem with a explicit cast of the function pointer to (Callback::*operator())(int) before the type deduction takes place.
If you change the callback function to the following you do not require the two types to be identical and it compiles without the cast.

```
template< typename Callback_t>
bool callback( int x )
{
    return Callback_t()( x );
}
```

What I don't understand is why you add the virtual function. Wouldn't the following do the same, be more simple and readable and even faster (no virtual function call)? The doCall function would be required to be public.

```
template< typename Callback_t>
bool callback( int x )
{
    return Callback_t().doCall( x );
}
```

Another improvement would be to make the callback function static. It would be even more simple if the doCall functions would be static - this would make the callback function obsolete and would avoid creating a temporary to call doCall.

Comment: Thank for you answer. Some comment.
About the point if Callback::operator() exists. It exists since it is inherited from the base class and in fact the last three lines of code  I have posted in the question work properly. Indeed it seems to me more a compiler bug. Yes it is true I could remove the function point as template parameter but in that case I could handle only functor object while indeed I would have liked to be more flexible allowing the user to specify also member functions in the case he prefers to have one single class implementing all the callbacks as member functions.  ...

Comment: .. About why I have defined the operator() and the virtual doCall. This is a pattern called template method. Yes in the example above it is useless but you can imagine that in the operator() into the CallbackBase are implemented some pre-operations and post-operations executed before and after the call of the callback function implemented in each derived class. An example could to take stats about execution time of the doCall.

Comment: @simone I don't believe in a compiler bug. I tried to compile your code on gcc and on visual studio with the same result. In Visual Studio the error message is: cannot convert from 'bool (__thiscall CallbackBase::* )(int)' to 'bool (__thiscall Callback::* const )(int)'. There is no function Callback::operator() it just calls the one from the base class. The following does neither compile in any of the mentioned compilers: typedef void (Callback::*func)(int);
func f = &Callback::operator();

Comment: I am using gcc version 4.6.0 20110603 (Red Hat 4.6.0-10) (GCC) and the following typedef bool (Callback::*Function_t)( int ); Function_t aFunction = &Callback::operator(); (Callback().*aFunction)( 5 ); works properly (be sure you public extend CallbackBase). This is the main reason I think it is a bug.

Comment: @simone edited the answer to explain exactly whats happening there

Comment: Thanks.Yes indeed it is a template resolution issue. Not clear how I can explicitly cast the pointer. I should do it at the call of the   aFSM.addCallback( "two", &FSM::callback< Callback, &Callback::operator() > ); into the template parameter but I am not allowed to do it.

Comment: @simone I'd really recommend you to think again about your code. To me it looks overcomplex for what it tries to do. If you use gcc 4.6 perhaps functional from c++-0x is a option?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4128/discussion-between-david-feurle-and-simone)